# Ionic Http Request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, paypal

I'm following the documentation [paypal-payment_get](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_get),
and using this command through the command prompt, returns me the required data, but does not
I know how to use this within my Ionic project. Can anyone give me an idea?

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY- 
0US81985GW1191216KOY7OXA \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

my service code:

`getPayment() {
var token = 'Bearer A21AAGZftCOieiS3hugdDfR4IcDLyQR7X8ulshgTAIg6_PXj8G5xo-BZFPERYjKE2Xll67mCS9W0xrcQXugcIN_7WnhkVEBkw';
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", [token]).set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    }
    return this.http.get("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-0US81985GW1191216KOY7OXA", httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  };`

and my component

```
 this.authService.getPayment().subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: You can get information about HTTP requests in Ionic in their documentation here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are on Ionic 2+ and Angular 4.3+ you should follow this guidance:

https://angular.io/guide/http

In your case you want to create a GET method in your provider ~like this:

```
  getPayment() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", [HERE USE VAR WITH AUTH TOKEN]).set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    }
    return this.http.get("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-0US81985GW1191216KOY7OXA", httpOptions)
      .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  };
```

In your component you want to call this method and subscribe to its results:

```
getPayment() {
    this.yourProvider.getPayment().subscribe((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
    })
}
```

Don't forget to import all required things and please share your current component's code if you struggle.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding! I did not know how to implement the code yet. I'm reading the documentation.
I am getting the following error:  GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-0US81985GW1191216KOY7OXA 401 (Unauthorized)

What am I doing wrong ?

I added my code in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. I researched a little more and I got the result with your help. THx

Comment: to get the access token, do I need to send my Client ID and Secret, where can I add these parameters?

Comment: Hey, I think you need to read carefully how exactly Paypal's API works and post a new question tagging it with paypal API. Normally you obtain token by authorizing your service via service to service call and then you could grant client just the token, but I never worked with Paypal API;/

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have read and read, but I am also new in this area, so a little trouble, but netão .. I get the Token as in my question, through the command prompt, I do not know how to automatically generate with the credentials.

Comment: curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \ -H "Accept: application/json" \ -H "Accept-Language: pt_BR" \ -u "MY-CLIENT_ID:MY-SECRET"\ -d "grant_type=client_credentials"